# Mule ESB: Connect to https service

Tags: java, service, https, esb, mule

Can someone show me a small example of how to create a mule flow to send requests to a https service? I tried to do it, but I get the following errors:

```
INFO 2012-09-21 21:40:40,980 [[myapp_kareo].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest: Content-Type not set on outgoing request, defaulting to: text/plain
WARN 2012-09-21 21:40:41,081 [[myapp_kareo].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString: Could not close stream
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:308) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:170)
```

etc...

I see at least 2 strange things:

- `org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest`: Content-Type not set on outgoing request, defaulting to: text/plain - I don't know from where I get this, the content type is set on all endpoints to text/xml.
- `org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToString`: Could not close stream - I cannot explain where this comes from...

My xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" proxyHostname="localhost" proxyPort="80" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <https:tls-key-store path="/src/main/app/keystore/javakeystore.jks" storePassword="somepassword"/>
</https:connector>
<flow name="KareoFlow1" doc:name="KareoFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="kareo" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="SomeApp"/>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="webservice.kareo.com/" port="443" path="services/soap/2.1/KareoServices.svc" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="Kareo"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not enough information: Mule version? Configuration? How to reproduce the issues?

Comment: I just added the xml configuration to the question

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of sending request to HTTPS will be as follows :-

```
<https:connector name="httpsBSConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" proxyHostname="proxy-nc.abc.com" proxyPort="80" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true">
     <https:tls-key-store path="${keystore.path}" keyPassword="${keystore.password}" storePassword="${keystore.password}"/>
     <https:tls-server path="${truststore.path}" storePassword="${truststore.password}"/>
</https:connector>

<https:outbound-endpoint address="https://${url}:${port}${path}" doc:name="getDataCall" exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" connector-ref="httpsBSConnector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This gentlemen seems to of solved his own issue of setting up a https service. Perhaps extracting some information from his example can guide you.  He had a different error, as for your stream errors I want to say the port is closed.

http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/https_connector_working_example_wanted

Including your mule configuration would let others help you more.