# HTTPS WS consumer having errors when deployed to mule runtime. (woking fine in Anypoint studio)

Tags: web-services, https, mule

I am having issues on my https ws whenit was deployed to mule runtime compared to Anypoint studio. Im using mule 3.7.3

I am getting timeout errors but didnt experience it in anypoint studio

```
    2016-05-05 11:24:50,286 [[activestreamtestmulti-v12].activestreamFlow1.stage1.02] WARN  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService#{http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}invoke has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.process(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:130) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.process(WSConsumer.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:287) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumerConfig$1.process(WSConsumerConfig.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.processNext(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.processNext(MuleUniversalConduit.java:388) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:282) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:193) ~[?:?]
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Poll timeout expired
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$AsyncPollTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1499) ~[?:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$AsyncPollTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1477) ~[?:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158) ~[?:?]
2016-05-05 11:24:50,301 [[activestreamtestmulti-v12].activestreamFlow1.stage1.02] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Poll timeout expired (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$AsyncPollTimeoutWorker:1499 (null)
2. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:287 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Poll timeout expired
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$AsyncPollTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1499)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$AsyncPollTimeoutWorker.doWork(SingleEndpointPool.java:1477)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.DelayedExecutor$DelayedRunnable.run(DelayedExecutor.java:158)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

this is my https config

ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="StockMovementData_WSDL3.wsdl" service="StockMovementData_OutService" port="HTTPS_Port" serviceAddress="https://test.com/SOAPAdapter/"  doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Configuration">

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"  responseTimeout="30000000" protocol="HTTPS" usePersistentConnections="false">
    <http:basic-authentication username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxxxx"/>
    <tcp:client-socket-properties connectionTimeout="300000000" />
</http:request-config>
```

P.S. Its working fine when using http

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the keystore for a https request.

You can refer to this post:

[Mule ESB: Connect to https service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546700/mule-esb-connect-to-https-service)

HTTPS requires certificates for connection. You can try out that one.

Comment: Actually, it's not required. If not set Mule will use the JVM truststore, which will usually contain most CA certificates and thus allow connections to services with certificates signed by those.